# background/Asynchronous process using Threading or Delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, delegates

At My website
   1. After filling form Inserting that record in SQL database
   2. In Next Line I take some class object then send to Matching with other record
   3. In matching application taking so much time

Now I have decided I will put matching process in background/Asynchronous  by using Threading or Delegate

My Previous code was:
    1. Inserting all information in database
                objclsBbDAL.InsertAcquirePrvider(objAcqProvBL);

```
2. Matching related record with other record in database
            clsMatchMakingDAL objclsMatchMakingDAL = new clsMatchMakingDAL();
            objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqProvBL);
```

Q 1. **Which one is best way to run process in background/Asynchronous - Threading or Delegate**

Now I am using Threading:

```
objclsBbDAL.InsertAcquirePrvider(objAcqProvBL);
//Threading
CallMatchMakingOnDiffThread(objAcqProvBL);

private void CallMatchMakingOnDiffThread(clsAcquireProviderBL objAcqPro)
{
    clsMatchMakingDAL objclsMatchMakingDAL = new clsMatchMakingDAL();
    Thread objThread = new Thread(() => objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro));
    objThread.Start();
}
```

Q2. **How can do this task with Delegate?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are like callbacks, you use them to notify that an asynchronous task has been completed, meaning the thread needs to call an event, which should have a delegate hooked onto it.

For example:

```
public struct ThreadData
{
    public int handle;
    public string details;
    public ThreadData(int handle, string details)
    {
        this.handle = handle;
        this.details = details;
    }
}
public class ThreadWorker
{
    private List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    public int BeginAsyncWork(string details)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        threads.Add(thread);
        thread.Start(new ThreadData(threads.Count - 1, details));
        return threads.Count - 1;
    }
    private void ThreadMethod(object parameter)
    {
        ThreadData data = (ThreadData)parameter;
        Console.WriteLine(data.details);
        if (ThreadFinished != null) { ThreadFinished(data.handle); }
    }
    public delegate void ThreadEndDelegate(int handle);
    public event ThreadEndDelegate ThreadFinished;
}
public static class Program
{
    private static int[] handles;
    public static void Main()
    {
        handles = new int[4];
        ThreadWorker worker = new ThreadWorker();
        worker.ThreadFinished += new ThreadWorker.ThreadEndDelegate(OnThreadFinished);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            handles[i] = worker.BeginAsyncWork("working: " + i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void OnThreadFinished(int handle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread: " + handle + " finished");
        handles[handle] = 0;
    }
}
```

It's long winded but it allows for full control over your threads.

EDIT:

Untested code. The shortest possible solution I could think of.

```
objclsBbDAL.InsertAcquirePrvider(objAcqProvBL);
//Threading
CallMatchMakingOnDiffThread(objAcqProvBL);

private void OnMatchAcquired(object match)
{
//do work with found match
}
private event Action<object> MatchAcquired = new Action<object>(OnMatchAcquired);

private void CallMatchMakingOnDiffThread(clsAcquireProviderBL objAcqPro)
{
    clsMatchMakingDAL objclsMatchMakingDAL = new clsMatchMakingDAL();
    Thread objThread = new Thread(
() => object match = (object)objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro); if(ThreadComplete!=nil){MatchAcquired(match);}
);
    objThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is an example of threading with delegates. Your answer is not what he asked for i guess. But also his question is out of misconception.

Comment: Ah well, at least it gave me some practise with threads. Forgot how awkward the evented thread design is to set up.

Comment: This is good ..But i what short code I know that we can do this in 3-4 line of code ..

Comment: My Simple Question is I want to put my matchmaking task asynchronous . I did  by using Threading ...1. How can I do by using Delegate ? 2. which one is fast - Threading or delegate

Comment: Threading and delegates are two completely different things! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Comment: Yes ...Right Pharap .....But if I want to use any of both for background process then which one is fast ?

Comment: Using them both together is fast. Events are only slightly slower than regular method calls and they are much more flexible. Events/Delegates on their own are good, Multithreading is fast, using both together is both fast and flexible.

Comment: This is so longwinded. Although thread and delegates are a completely different things delegates can be invoked asynchronously (that will execute them on another thread) without all this boilerplate code. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: The sample you show does not account for the eventuality that the thread actually returns important information.

Comment: The original posters question does not state that the information needs to be collected. Plus my answer actually states how you could hook-up a callback to be notified when the execution is collected.

Comment: An event handler is a callback, just a more structured one. Either way, an answer has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do background processing with only a delegate.
A delegate is totally different from  a thread or an asynchronous process.
You can understand a delegate as a pointer to a function.
Threads use delegates to execute a certain function but delegates alone are not any kind of background execution.
Doing what you mentioned up-there would run the process in background, but you have to know the costs for running the operation in background and in this way. You also need to know if it does really needs to be run in background or it only needs optimization.

Comment: How can I do same thing with delegate ? Which I did using Threading ?

Comment: Thread objThread = new Thread(() => objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro));

The part "() => objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro)" is where you provided a delegate for the thread.

Comment: Hi Siraj ....You meand ........new Thread( delegate() { objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro)} );

Comment: @KrantiSingh exactly that is how your provide a delegate, also the implementation you wrote upthere is also a delegate provider but with different syntax. I repeate a delegate is only a safe pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way (for me at least) is to use a delegate and BeginInvoke, which will return immediately and for which you can supply a callback that is executed when the delegate is finished.
More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

In your sample code I do not see, that you need to be notified, when the operation is finished so you could do something like this:

```
new Action(() =>
{
    clsMatchMakingDAL objclsMatchMakingDAL = new clsMatchMakingDAL();
    objclsMatchMakingDAL.AcquireMatch(objAcqPro);
}).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

This would execute the matching functionality on another thread that is managed by .Net for you. If you need to be notified on completion, then the first argument to the `BeginInvoke` call could be another delegate to handle the completion event.